# Probability of the last element being chosen is $b$

Tags: probability

I have two elements: $a$ and $b$

Every step, I randomly choose one of these two elements to add to a box. Each element has a $1/2$ chance of being chosen. For example:

> Step 1: I choose $a$, the box now is $\{a\}$
>
> Step 2: I choose $a$, the box now is $\{a, a\}$
>
> Step 3: I choose $b$, the box now is $\{a, a, b\}$...

I stop when I have at least 14 $a$s OR at least 33 $b$s. What's the probability that the last element I choose is $b$?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Binomial expansions will help you

Comment: Hint:  the game must be resolved in $46$ or fewer rounds (why?).  Accordingly, argue that this is the same as asking for the probability that, in $46$ tosses of a fair coin, you get at least $33$ heads.

Comment: @lulu so if i wanted to find the probability that the last element I choose is $a$, it would be like $46$ coin tosses getting at least $14$ heads?

Comment: Correct. $\quad$.

Comment: @lulu keep on posting! I've learned a great deal of math from you

Comment: @MatthewPilling  Kind of you to say.  Thanks!